# Wrong regexp query for elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have some problems with the regexp query for elasticsearch. In my index there's a text field with comma-separated numeric values (IDs), f.e.

```
2,140,3,2495
```

And I have the following query term:

```
"regexp" : {
  "myIds" : {
    "value" : "^2495,|,2495,|,2495$|^2495$",
    "boost" : 1
  }
}
```

But my result list is empty.

Let me say that I know that regexp queries are kind of slow but the index still exists and is filled with millions of documents so unfortunately it's not an option to restructure it. So I need a regex solution.

Comment: In ES regex, patterns are anchored by default, the `^` and `$` are literal chars. Try `"2495,.*|.*,2495,.*|.*,2495|2495"`. Or, I think you may use a simpler `"(.*,)?2495(,.*)?"`

Answer (score 0):

In ElasticSearch regex, patterns are anchored by default, the `^` and `$` are treated as literal chars.

What you mean to use is `"2495,.*|.*,2495,.*|.*,2495|2495"` - `2495,` at the start of string, `,2495,` in the middle, `,2495` at the end or a whole string equal to `2495`.

Or, you may use a simpler

```
"(.*,)?2495(,.*)?"
```

That means

- `(.*,)?` - an optional text (not including line breaks) ending with `,`
- `2495` - your value
- `(,.*)?` - an optional text (not including line breaks) ending with `,`

Here is an [online demo showing how this expression works](https://regex101.com/r/xmTFNV/1) (not a proof though).

Comment: Your second solution is very smart because it's simple and if I will build a query with several IDs the regexp will not be too complex. But the solution has one disadvantage: If I query for the ID "9" it will also match because my example string from above has the "2495". But this is the wrong behavior because 9 is not 2495. Is there a way to keep the query simple like in your example but prevent the incorrect matching?

Comment: @altralaser Do you want to say `"(.*,)?9(,.*)?"` returns `2495`? [It should not](https://regex101.com/r/xmTFNV/2). If it is a Java regex here, then try `(?<![,])9(?![^,])` or `"^(.*,)?9(,.*)?$"`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to work but run in another problem now. I built the string as follows:

```
(.*,)?2495(,.*)?|(.*,)?10(,.*)?|(.*,)?898(,.*)?
```

It works good for a few IDs but if I have let's say 50 IDs, then ES throws an exception which says that the regexp is too complex to process.
Is there a way to simplify the regexp or restructure the query it selves?

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider upvoting/accepting it rather than re-posting as your answer. Since you have a new problem, you should post a new question.